# Angular JS services

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create several services in the same module but in separate files. I can not manage to get the services to load. Please let me know where i am going wrong:

app.js:

```
angular.module('ngBoilerplate', [
    'ngBoilerplate.commonServices' ... ]
```

services.js:

```
angular.module('ngBoilerplate.commonServices',[]);
```

service1.js:

```
angular.module('ngBoilerplate.commonServices').service('egService', function() { ...
```

service2.js:

```
angular.module('ngBoilerplate.commonServices').service('userService', function() {...
```

Comment: How do you know they are not loading?

Comment: avoid **.(dot)** in module names, use **_(underscore)** instead

Comment: I get an error saying that it can not find the provider for the service

Comment: ncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngBoilerplate_commonServices' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://er...<omitted>...es angular.js:78
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: egServiceProvider <- egService

Comment: changed to underscore still didnt work

Comment: is services.js loaded before app.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be your load order.

Assuming you're just using script tags and not requirejs or something like that your script tags should be in the following order for the modules to work as you've defined:

```
<script src="services.js"></script>
<script src="services1.js"></script>
<script src="services2.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Comment: I was using grunt to include my JS files and it added them in the wrong order. Thanks for the help

Comment: I'd recommend using requirejs with angular for this very reason. There's an example project here https://github.com/tnajdek/angular-requirejs-seed